# Авторизация через Госуслуги

Tags: php, oauth, есиа

Пробую сделать авторизацию через Госуслуги.
Порядок подключения сайта понятен. Непонятно как работать с сертификатами.

Посмотрел несколько примеров реализации как на PHP (например https://github.com/fr05t1k/esia), так и на других языках.

Везде идет речь о сертификате (1 файл), о закрытом ключе (1 файл) и пароле к закрытому ключу (строка).

Что я имею из этого:

- Пароль к закрытому ключу
- Некие сертификаты, общедоступные по ссылке http://esia.gosuslugi.ru/public/esia.zip
  Я так понимаю что из них мне нужен только один, в зависимости от типа подписи.
- Файлы, которые прислал заказчик (он же регистрировал сайт на Госуслугах).

Файлы от заказчика содержат один файл с расширением `cer` (Еще один сертификат?) и папку с несколькими файлами с расширением `key` (header.key, masks.key, primary.key и тд)

Вопросы: Как мне эти данные использовать? Какой из сертификатов мне нужен? Какой из файлов key - закрытый ключ? Или мне надо произвести какие-то действия и сгенерить из них закрытый ключ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прошлый ответ теперь неактуален (для нас по крайней мере).
Требования изменились и нам надо было использовать криптопро в любом случае.

Решили это использованием образа https://hub.docker.com/r/required/cryptopro.
Гляньте внимательно как его устанавливать и импортировать ключи. Вам придется скачать себе репозиторий и собирать из локальных файлов а не просто указать имя образа.

Внутри образа надо поднять любым доступным способом апишку, которая будет принимать на вход строку, а отдавать на выход подписанную строку. Это все, для чего нужен этот образ.

Команда для подписи:

```
#!/bin/bash

cryptcp -signf -dir "/import" -der -strict -cert -detached -thumbprint "$1" -pin "$2" "/import/message" > /dev/null 2>&1
signResult=$?
if [ "$signResult" != "0" ]; then
  exit $signResult
fi
cat "/import/message.sgn"
rm -f "/import/message" "/import/message.sgn"
```

Скрипт апишки:

```
<?php

$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
list($path,) = explode('?', $request);

switch ($path) {
    case '/sign':
        $content = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $content = str_replace("\n", '', $content);
        $content = str_replace("\r", '', $content);
        file_put_contents('/import/message', $content);
        $cmd = '/import/scripts/signf-cryptcp ' . $_GET['query'] . ' ' . $_GET['pin'];
        $data = [
            'status' => 'ok',
            'cmd' => $cmd,
            'signedContent' => safeBase64(shell_exec($cmd))
        ];
        echo json_encode($data);
        break;
}

function safeBase64($string)
{
    file_put_contents('/import/sig', $string);
    $encoded = $string;
    $encoded = base64_encode($encoded);
    $encoded = str_replace(array('+', '/', '='), array('-', '_', ''), $encoded);
    file_put_contents('/import/sig-encoded', $encoded);
    return $encoded;
}
```

Апишка дергается таким образом:

```
$query = 'find_type='.$findType.'&query='.$certQuery.'&pin='.$keyPin;
$cmd = 'echo "'.$message.'" | curl -sS -X POST --data-binary @- "'.$apiUrl.'/sign?'.$query.'"';
```

- $findType = 'sha1': метод поиска сертификата в контейнере
- $certQuery: хеш загруженного в контейнер с криптопро сертификата (типа
  идентификатора).
- $keyPin: Пин, или ключ, или мнемоника. Точно не помню как это в терминах госуслуг или криптопро.
- $message: Строка для подписи
- $apiUrl: урлик апишки в контейнере криптопро

Итак, мы умеем подписывать строки. Что дальше?

В качестве OAuth клиента использовали https://github.com/ekapusta/oauth2-esia

Но в итоге пришлось кое-что переписать

```
<?php

/* ПРИШЛОСЬ ПОЛНОСТЬЮ СКОПИПАСТИТЬ КЛАСС Ekapusta\OAuth2Esia\Provider\EsiaProvider, т.к. некоторые вещи private */

namespace app\components\oauth;

use Ekapusta\OAuth2Esia\Interfaces\Provider\ProviderInterface;
use Ekapusta\OAuth2Esia\Interfaces\Security\SignerInterface;
use Ekapusta\OAuth2Esia\Interfaces\Token\ScopedTokenInterface;
use Ekapusta\OAuth2Esia\Token\EsiaAccessToken;
use InvalidArgumentException;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Parsing\Encoder;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Grant\AbstractGrant;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericResourceOwner;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Token\AccessToken;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Tool\BearerAuthorizationTrait;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;

class EsiaProvider extends AbstractProvider implements ProviderInterface
{
    use BearerAuthorizationTrait;

    const RESOURCES = __DIR__.'/../../resources/';

    protected $defaultScopes = ['openid', 'fullname'];

    protected $remoteUrl = 'https://esia.gosuslugi.ru';

    protected $remoteCertificatePath = self::RESOURCES.'esia.prod.cer';

    /**
     * @var SignerInterface
     */
    private $signer;

    /**
     * @var Encoder
     */
    private $encoder;

    public function __construct(array $options = [], array $collaborators = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($options, $collaborators);
        if (!filter_var($this->remoteUrl, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Remote URL is not provided!');
        }
        if (!file_exists($this->remoteCertificatePath)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Remote certificate is not provided!');
        }

        if (isset($collaborators['signer']) && $collaborators['signer'] instanceof SignerInterface) {
            $this->signer = $collaborators['signer'];
            $this->encoder = new Encoder();
        } else {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Signer is not provided!');
        }
    }

    public function getBaseAuthorizationUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('/aas/oauth2/ac');
    }

    protected function getAuthorizationParameters(array $options)
    {
        $options = [
            'access_type' => 'online',
            'approval_prompt' => null,
            'timestamp' => $this->getTimeStamp(),
        ] + parent::getAuthorizationParameters($options);

        return $this->withClientSecret($options);
    }

    /**
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function withClientSecret(array $params)
    {
        $message = $params['scope'].$params['timestamp'].$params['client_id'].$params['state'];
        $signature = $this->signer->sign($message);
        // $params['client_secret'] = $this->encoder->base64UrlEncode($signature);
    $params['client_secret'] = $signature; // т.к. криптопро возвращает уже кодированную строку

        return $params;
    }

    protected function getRandomState($length = 32)
    {
        return Uuid::uuid4()->toString();
    }

    public function generateState()
    {
        return $this->getRandomState();
    }

    private function getTimeStamp()
    {
        return date('Y.m.d H:i:s O');
    }

    public function getBaseAccessTokenUrl(array $params)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('/aas/oauth2/te');
    }

    public function getResourceOwnerDetailsUrl(AccessToken $token)
    {
        $embeds = $this->getResourceOwnerEmbeds($token);

        return $this->getUrl('/rs/prns/'.$token->getResourceOwnerId().'?embed=('.implode(',', $embeds).')');
    }

    private function getResourceOwnerEmbeds(ScopedTokenInterface $token)
    {
        $allowedScopes = $token->getScopes();

        $embedsToScopes = [
            'contacts.elements' => [
                'contacts',
                'email',
                'mobile',
            ],
            'addresses.elements' => [
                'contacts',
            ],
            'documents.elements' => [
                'id_doc',
                'medical_doc',
                'military_doc',
                'foreign_passport_doc',
                'drivers_licence_doc',
                'birth_cert_doc',
                'residence_doc',
                'temporary_residence_doc',
            ],
            'vehicles.elements' => [
                'vehicles',
            ],
            'organizations.elements' => [
                'usr_org',
            ],
        ];

        $allowedEmbeds = [];
        foreach ($embedsToScopes as $embed => $scopes) {
            if (count(array_intersect($allowedScopes, $scopes))) {
                $allowedEmbeds[] = $embed;
            }
        }

        return $allowedEmbeds;
    }

    private function getUrl($path)
    {
        return $this->remoteUrl.$path;
    }

    protected function getDefaultScopes()
    {
        return $this->defaultScopes;
    }

    protected function getScopeSeparator()
    {
        return ' ';
    }

    protected function getAccessTokenRequest(array $params)
    {
        $params = $params + [
            'scope' => 'openid',
            'state' => $this->getRandomState(),
            'timestamp' => $this->getTimeStamp(),
            'token_type' => 'Bearer',
        ];

        return parent::getAccessTokenRequest($this->withClientSecret($params));
    }

    protected function checkResponse(ResponseInterface $response, $data)
    {
        if ($response->getStatusCode() >= 400 || isset($data['error'])) {
            throw new IdentityProviderException(
                isset($data['error']) ? $data['error'] : $response->getReasonPhrase(),
                $response->getStatusCode(),
                (string) $response->getBody()
            );
        }
    }

    protected function createAccessToken(array $response, AbstractGrant $grant)
    {
        return new EsiaAccessToken($response, $this->remoteCertificatePath);
    }

    protected function createResourceOwner(array $response, AccessToken $token)
    {
        $response = ['resourceOwnerId' => $token->getResourceOwnerId()] + $response;

        return new GenericResourceOwner($response, 'resourceOwnerId');
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace app\components\oauth;

use Ekapusta\OAuth2Esia\Security\Signer;

class CryptoProApiSigner extends Signer
{
    public function __construct($params)
    {
        $this->keyPin = $params['keyPin'] ?? null;
        $this->findType = $params['findType'] ?? 'sha1';
        $this->certQuery = $params['certQuery'] ?? null;
        $this->apiUrl = $params['apiUrl'] ?? null;
    }

    public function sign($message)
    {
        $response = $this->request($message);
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
        $sig = $response['signedContent'] ?? null;
        file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/message', $message);
        file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/sig.json', print_r($response, true));
        file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/sig', $sig);
        return $sig;
    }

    public function request($message)
    {
        $certQuery = 'find_type=' . $this->findType . '&query=' . $this->certQuery . '&pin=' . $this->keyPin;
        $cmd = 'echo "' . $message . '" | curl -sS -X POST --data-binary @- "' . $this->apiUrl . '/sign?' . $certQuery . '"';
        file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/cmd', $cmd);
        return shell_exec($cmd);
    }
}
```

Как использовать

```
<?php

$provider = new EsiaProvider([
    'clientId'      => $this->config['client_id'] ?? null,
    'redirectUri'   => $redirectUrl ?? $this->config['redirect_uri'] ?? null,
    'defaultScopes' => $this->config['default_scope'] ?? null,
    'remoteUrl' => $this->config['portal_url'] ?? null,
    'remoteCertificatePath' => $this->config['remote_cert_path'] ?? null,
], [
    'signer' => new CryptoProApiSigner(
        [
            'keyPin' => $this->config['pin'],
            'certQuery' => $this->config['cert_sha1'],
            'apiUrl' => $this->config['signer_api_url']
        ]
    )
]);

// получение урлика для редиректа на госуслуги
$redirectUrl = $_POST['redirectUrl'];
$provider = $this->getProvider($redirectUrl);
$state = $provider->generateState();
$params = [
    'state' => $state,
];
try {
    $authUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl($params);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
return [
    'authUrl' => $authUrl,
    'state' => $state
];

// получение токена и данных
$redirectUrl = $_POST['redirectUrl'];
$provider = $this->getProvider($redirectUrl);
$accessToken = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', ['code' => $_POST['code'] ?? null]);
if (!$accessToken) {
    return null;
}
$esiaPersonData = $provider->getResourceOwner($accessToken);
if (!$esiaPersonData) {
    return null;
}
$userDataArray = $esiaPersonData->toArray();
return $userDataArray;
```

P.S. Код выдергивался и правился из проекта, поэтому на 100% рабочесть не претендует, но зато видно сценарий.

Answer (score 6):

Разобрались в ситуации.

В итоге ключи, что прислал клиент (6 закрытых и 1 сертификат) могут быть импортированы только в криптопро. И работать с ними можно только с ПО криптопро (https://www.cryptopro.ru/). С их ПО получается только подписывать файлы, запросы - нет. Плюс это платно.

В итоге нашли докер контейнер, который умеет работать с ГОСТ шифрованием (https://github.com/rnixik/docker-openssl-gost/tree/master/php-fpm-gost). Сделали для него простой rest api для проксирования запросов к ЕСИА с использованием библиотеки (https://github.com/ekapusta/oauth2-esia)

Для работы с этой библиотекой необходимо преобразовать ключ и сертификат.

Ключ преобразовали с помощью этого https://github.com/garex/nodejs-gost-crypto
Сертификат преобразовали с помощью этого https://ssl4less.ru/faq/ehniceskie-voprosy/onvertirovanie-sertifikatov-pem-p7b-pfx-der.html

Comment: Здравствуйте. Мне нужна помощь по решению такой же задаче. Как с вами связаться?

Comment: @ДмитрийМатвиенко, напишите мне на noir.garbage.ii@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

> Везде идет речь о сертификате (1 файл), о закрытом ключе (1 файл) и пароле к закрытому ключу (строка)

Для обмена с ЕСИА потребуется шифрование, поэтому у вас должен быть свой RSA-ключ для подписи. Закрытый ключ находится у вас, публичный сертификат выгружается в кабинет ЕСИА.

> Некие сертификаты, общедоступные по ссылке http://esia.gosuslugi.ru/public/esia.zip

Поскольку ЕСИА тоже будет присылать вам шифрованную информацию, то вам потребуется публичный сертификат ЕСИА, чтобы расшифровать эту информацию.

> Файлы от заказчика содержат один файл с расширением cer

Скорей всего - это публичный сертификат. Можете попробовать его открыть. В windows должно открыться стандартное окно с информацией о сертификате.

> и папку с несколькими файлами с расширением key (header.key, masks.key, primary.key и тд)

А вот тут сказать сложно. Похоже, что клиент сгенерировал ключ на флешке средствами крипто-про или наподобие, а потом просто скопировал каталог. Вот тут он не прав. Надо выяснять конкретные требования заказчика по интеграции

Для авторизации через госуслуги можно использовать, например, самоподписанные сертификаты:

Сначала создать закрытый ключ и запрос на сертификат

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout domain.key -out domain.csr -sha256
```

в процессе генерации будет запрос на воод пароля к закрытому ключу.

Потом выпустить публичный сертификат для него

```
openssl x509 -signkey domain.key -in domain.csr -req -days 1825 -out domain.crt -sha256
```

у вас будет два файла domain.key (закрытый ключ) и domain.crt (сертификат). Сертификат потом надо будет выгрузить в кабинет ЕСИА.

> Как мне эти данные использовать?

Очень помог в интеграции с ЕСИА пакет https://github.com/ekapusta/oauth2-esia
Описание работы с ним https://habr.com/ru/post/358834/

Кстати, если посмотрите тесты на гитхабе, то найдете там мнемонику для тестовой организации и готовые ключи для нее. Можно будет протестировать.

Comment: Соответственно заказчик мне 2 файла должен вернуть - ключ и сертификат?

Comment: Надо выяснить как он формировал ключ и какие требования к нему предъявлялись. Если он формировал ключ через крипто-про с гостовскими алгоритмами то можно получить дополнительный геморрой. Если закрытый ключ не экспортируется с е-токена в файл, то придется искать библиотеки, которые работают не с файлом, а с е-токеном, который должен будет все время вставлен в сервер. Нужно выяснить у заказчика, а зачем ему это нужно. Требуют ли от него это специально? Возможно он сам напутал и отдал вам сертификат доступа к своему кабинету на госуслугах, который вовсе не нужен для создания аут-ии на госуслугах

Comment: Вам требуется закрытый ключ и сертификат. Они могут формироваться самостоятельно (как писал выше). Так что проясните с заказчиком. Вполне возможно он сам мало что понимает в авторизации через госуслуги.

Comment: Прежде чем начинать работу, выясните еще у заказчика, предоставили ли ему песочницу для разработки. А то вы и протестировать ничего не сможете

Comment: Искал как продолжить общение в чате, но не нашел как это сделать =) Хотел подробнее узнать про песочницу. Что это? Как выглядит? Где узнать про это?

Comment: Процедура интеграции с ЕСИА государственных и муниципальных организаций http://esia.pro/integraciya_esia_gos_org

Comment: _Искал как продолжить общение в чате_ когда количество комментов достигнет определенного значения, то система сама предложит

Comment: Их сертификаты выпущены по ГОСТ-2001. Видимо так и должно быть (несколько key файлов). Вобщем необходимо установить на сервер сертификаты, что они скинули (непонятно как). Наверно проще будет использовать докер контейнер, который умеет работать с GOST сертификатами (https://hub.docker.com/r/rnix/openssl-gost/) Но опять же... нигде не нашел ситуации с целой папкой ключей... везде - 1 сертификат и 1 ключ.

Comment: Я все больше склоняюсь к мысли, что клиент напутал и скинул вам свою эцп. Тут он рискует с безопасностью. Авторизация на сайте через госуслуги не требует квалифицированной эцп. Можете проверить. Скопируйте выданные файлы в каталог на флешку. Поставьте 30-дневку крипто-про. Крипто про должен найти ключ на флешке. Установите личный сертификат, и попробуйте войти по этому ключу на госуслуги. Если вошли под его организацией - то мои предположения подтвердились)))

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98479/discussion-between-dmitry-kozlov-and-skywave).